# Html.from HTML is not formatting html tags

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I am getting following response from service and It contains following HTML tags & HTML codes.

> This team will get &#8216;a different feel to it&#8217

I am using following approach to remove these tags.

```
     var title: String

     title = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                Html.fromHtml(title, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString()
            } else {
                Html.fromHtml(title).toString()
        }
```

This code is not removing these HTML codes.

Comment: Is the response encoded like `&amp;#8216;` as in your post, or did you escape `&` to `&amp;` when posting your question?

Comment: &amp got converted by SO, the response is `&amp;#8216; `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `Html.fromHtml()` twice, first pass to convert `&amp;`, second pass for the "real" conversion:

```
fun fromHtml(title: String) = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    Html.fromHtml(title, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString()
} else {
    Html.fromHtml(title).toString()
}

fun fromHtmlTwoPasses(title: String) = fromHtml(fromHtml(title))

val title = "This team get &amp;#8216;a different feel to it&amp;#8217"
val result = fromHtmlTwoPasses(title)
// result = "This team get ‘a different feel to it’"
```

Credit goes to laalto for suspecting that actual response contained `&amp;`.

Comment: Thank You So Much  !! This just fixed the issue :)

Comment: Hi again! Please don't forget to mark the answer as Accepted!

Answer (score 1):

It only supports a small subset of codes and tags.  Its not meant for general display of HTML, but for quick and simple markup.  If it isn't working for a code you need, change your string or use another technique entirely.

Comment: Thanks, i can't change the string i receive from server, but can look for other technique on my side. Can you guide me what other techniques are available to fix this.

Comment: I mean, for this a simple string replace would work.  Do a regex looking for &#NNNN;, lookup what unicode character that NNNN should be, and replace it with that.

Comment: ok thanks. just found out about StringEscapeUtils from `commons-lang3` , will check that

Answer (score 1):

From comments:

> `the response is &amp;#8216;`

That means there are really two levels of encoding. There's the XML entity `&#8216;` that is then further encoded to `&amp;#8216`. Decoding the content once turns it to `&#8216;`. To further decode that to [left single quotation mark](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2018/index.htm), you need to interpret it again with e.g. `Html.fromHtml()`.

Or better yet, if you can influence the service, fix it to not encode its responses.

Comment: Thanks a lot for identifying the issue :) I used the code from @Enselic, and it just fixed the issue